# JScrollPane doesn't come up on first page load

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a JScrollPane on a login page, basically after successfull login, it'll go to the second page where I should see the ScrollBar but the scrollbar dosn't show on first load, I have to refresh the page one more time, does anyone know why this happens?
Has anyone used JScrollPane before?

Thanks for your help.

```
$(function()
    {
    // this initialises the demo scollpanes on the page.
      $('#logos').jScrollPane();                
    });

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jScrollPane.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/scrollPane.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jScrollPane.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

     <div id="logos" class="scroll-pane">
     <a id="logo1" href=""><img src="" /></a>
     <a id="logo2" href=""><img src="" /></a>
                 .....
                 ......

</div>

</body>
```

Also I don't see any errors when using firebug.

after looking around the code I realize that I need to re-initialize the scroll-pane,

so after adding the following code still the scroll bar doesn't appear on first page load but as soon as I move the cursor it appears, so I was wondering how I can reinitialize it without the hover effect,

```
$(function() {
reinitialiseScrollPane = function()
                {
                    $('#logos').jScrollPane();
                }
                $('body').hover(function() {
                    reinitialiseScrollPane();
                });

});
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see any Javascript errors when loading it the first time? Check with Firebug for firefox, or Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari. It should load the first time. Refreshing the page to get this to work is a bad hack.

Comment: after using firebug, in the login page I get the following error
Warning:script panel was inactive during page load
but the scrolbar is in the second page (i.e login2.php)

Comment: Don't know what the problem is, but I have a hunch that this question could be related to what you're seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565478/jquery-scrollpane-ms-ajax-updatepanel-doesnt-work-after-post-back

Comment: just realized that the scroll-bar doesn't load up when there are images in the container div, cos on another page where there are images the scrollbar doen't load up either, any ideas please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future refrence, the problem was that when there are images the scroll Pane needs to be reinitialized, so the following code would solve the problem

```
$('#logos').jScrollPane({reinitialiseOnImageLoad: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to refresh the page automatically as a fix, then I would advise against it, as seems suspiciously like a bodge ;-)

Some code would be useful. Are you instantiating it within the documentready event? What browsers are you using? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: this is how I instantiate it.

$(function()
 {
 // this initialises the demo scollpanes on the page.
 $('div#logos').jScrollPane();
        });